# How to update a field when I'm writing a value in other field in OpenERP 7?

Tags: odoo, openerp-7

I'm a newbie with openerp and I'm trying how can I need to know how can i make a code that calculates the result in a field when I write a value in other field, example:

```
field1 = 5000 

field2 = field1 * 5
```

I've read the docs and tried whit programming functions but always get an error.

Comment: if you get an error than you should share with us. you can create on_change for `field1` field when it's change `field2` will be update. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it. I used this code:

```
def _get_salario_diario(self, cr, uid, ids, field_name, arg, context=None):
    res= {}
    for record in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        res[record.id]= record.month_wage / 30
    return res
_columns = {
    'month_wage': fields.float('Salario Mensual Bs.', digits=(16,2)),
    'diary_wage': fields.function(_get_salario_diario, method=True, type='float', string='Salario Diario Bs.', store=True),
}

def onchange_month_wage(self, cr, uid, ids, month_wage, context=None):
        vals = {}
        if month_wage > 0:
            vals['diary_wage'] = salario_mensual / 30
        return {'value': vals}
```

and in my XML file:

```
<field name='month_wage' on_change="onchange_month_wage(month_wage)"/>
<field name='diary_wage'/>
```

It solved my problem and my module works rightly.

Answer (score 0):

`onchange` is solution for your problem.

Here is example in .py side:

```
def onchange_field1(self, cr, uid, ids, field1, context=None):
    vals = {}
    if field1 > 0:
        vals['field12'] = field1 * 5
    return {'value': vals}
```

Here is example in .xml side:

```
<field name="field1" on_change="onchange_field1(field1)"/>
```

Comment: i get this error 

def on_change_month_wage(self, cr, uid, ids, month_wage, context=None):
                                                                          ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Comment: This is my code

def on_change_month_wage(self, cr, uid, ids, month_wage, context=None):
        res = {}
        if month_wage > 0:
            res['diary_wage'] = month_wage / 30
        return {'value': res}

month_wage':fields.float('Salario Mensual', digits=(16,2)),
                'diary_wage':fields.function(on_change_month_wage, type = 'float', string = 'Salario Diario'),

and in xml:

<field name="month_wage" string="Salario Mensual" on_change="on_change_month_wage(month_wage)"/>
<field name="diary_wage" string="Salario Diario"/>

Comment: You are mixing tabs and spaces. Don't do that. configure your editor to use *spaces only* for indentation; a good editor will insert 4 spaces every time you use the `TAB` key.

Comment: if this answer is help to solved your question than you may accept the answer with checked right. thanks

Comment: it solved a bit, but now, when i'm going to save the registry y get this error: "TypeError: on_change_month_wage() takes at most 6 arguments (7 given)"

Comment: yes i also give that question answer also but for this question you may accept this current answer. So other user will not give the answer for current question. In stackoverflow is help us a lot if we use this site in proper manner. Like if we solved the question than accept the answer. Why not take a tour of SO? From the right side `help => TOUR` it will help you a lot.